# Grails rendering plugin does not render images when deployed

Tags: pdf, grails, war, grails-plugin

I am generating a pdf using grails rendering plugin.
When in development, I include images using  tag with src to an image on server. It works fine, but not anymore when the app is deployed. The images just disappear.

I am redering through a template, so when i call this template to in gsp, it is ok (ie i see the html version of the pdf with the images), bu when called in my controller using renderPdf, no images.

Again only in deployed app (war), not in development.

Any hints?

EDIT: Under popular request here is the code:

the _pdf.gsp file can be as simple as

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head/>
  <body>
    <img src="path/to/image.jpg"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

the relevant part of the controller is

```
def pdf={
     renderPdf(template: "/file/pdf", filename: "myfile.pdf")
}
```

Comment: And the log output as well, if there is anything of interest there.

Comment: I have updated with my code. Note that inlining the image data is some kind of workaround, but too heavy for big images

Comment: Do you use embedded-plugins? Some paths will be different, when deploying to tomcat. Unzip your WAR and check where the images really are. I guess that the paths are just wrong.

Comment: actually, no since i render the html version of the template, and the image is present

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have been looking at this for two frustrating days, and have tried many things. My advice, and it is the advice that they do give in the documentation is to **stick to inline images**. By that I mean define the image in its byte form. You won't regret it, and you will be sure the rendering plugin will play nice with other plugins like ui-performance and resources.

First create the file object like so

```
def paid = new File(ApplicationHolder.application.parentContext.servletContext.getRealPath("/images/paid.jpg"))
```

then pass in the bytes of the file into the model

```
renderPdf(template:invoiceTemplate, model:[paidBytes:paid.bytes])
```

Now in your pdf template use the following tag:

```
<rendering:inlineJpeg bytes="${paidBytes}" />
```

If you have no dependency issues then you should be set.
If you do run into dependency issues like I did and noted [**HERE**](https://github.com/gpc/grails-rendering/issues/4), then look at the version of iText your pulling in.

Comment: actually i have also reach this conclusion in using inlining, which work pretty ok on one project, but the other, i have to report many images in the pdf, and the size of the pdf is growing fast with this method (several 10M for 3 pages document), and the server is kind of overloaded...

Comment: Glad to hear you came to the same conclusion :)

Comment: I found that specifying absolute urls will get the images to appear in the PDF so long as they are not being g-zipped. So that could be a backup plan for you. I'm interested to know: if you just specify the images as urls in the gsp, does this actually reduce the size of a PDF? I'm inclined to think it would have no affect on the size.

Comment: yes actually, the reason is that the image are embeded somehow in ascii mode when inlined, same as if you put data:image/png,%89PNG%0D%0A%1A%0A%00%00%00%0DIHDR%00%00%00%05%00%00%00%05%08%06%00%00%00%8Do%26%E5%00%00%004IDATx%DAe%8A%B1%0D%000%0C%C2%F2%2CK%96%BC%D0%8F9%81%88H%E9%D0%0E%96%C0%10%92%3E%02%80%5E%82%E4%A9*-%EEsw%C8%CC%11%EE%96w%D8%DC%E9*Eh%0C%151(%00%00%00%00IEND%AEB%60%82 in your browser

Comment: i undestood that when i rendered the template in a simple gsp page, instead of pdf

Answer (score 3):

It most certainly has to do with what's stated in the docs for the rendering plugin:

"All links to resources (e.g. images, css) must be accessible by the application . This is due to the linked resources being accessed by application and not a browser. Depending on your network config in production, this may require some special consideration."

Probable tip: If you are running Linux on your server, add your site's domain name to /etc/hosts so it resolves to 127.0.0.1. If other OS do accordingly.

Comment: well, i am sure the image is present, since as stated in my message, calling the template inside another gsp is ok (ie images are present) on the production server

Comment: btw i am using jetty as a server

Comment: Yes, the image is present and your browser finds it and displays it. However, the rendering plugin tries to find the image directly from the server as opposed to from your browser. Due to how the network is configured it most certainly can't find it and that's why you don't see it in the pdf. Try my tip!

Answer (score 1):

As wwwclaes says, it is about resources available **to the application**.

But, if you are using asset-pipeline, you can make it a little simpler.

Controller:

`def assetResourceLocator
...
    def myAction() {
    ...
        renderPdf(template:invoiceTemplate, model:[rl:assetResourceLocator])
    }
...`

Then in your template:

`<rendering:inlineJpeg bytes="${rl?.findAssetForURI('paid.jpg').byteArray}" />`

Now you can use rl for any number of images in your template without mucking up the model in the controller with presentation items.

Comment: It's better to use `resourceLocator.findAssetForURI('image.png').getInputStream().bytes` to avoid error in production.