# Grails Google Chart to a PDF

Tags: grails, google-visualization, export-to-pdf

im trying to export a Google chart to a PDF using a template but it does not accept javascript code. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the chart as an image and then you can inline it in the PDF for the grails rendering plugin. I haven't got an example to hand, but basically it's :

[Grails rendering plugin does not render images when deployed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209707/grails-rendering-plugin-does-not-render-images-when-deployed)

If you are using Google's "image charting" API then it's quite easy. Less so with the newer
javascript/svg ones.

Comment: but im using google chart tools, that is a javascript and a div label, i cant send a request with a div label.